# Is there any command-line to change my network mask in Windows shell?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, netmask

I have not been able to find nothing on the **netsh** command shell documentation for changing only the *netmask* configuration without modifying rest of it (*ip*, *gateway*, *DNSs* and so on).
The closest I know about is this one, that changes too *IP* and *gateway*:

```
netsh interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” static 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
```

Before attemping some more serious scripting about the problem, is there any way, like using *powershell*, *power tools*, *wmic*, or at least with some *[NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/)*, *[PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals)* or similar command-line utility?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the correct way is to specify the IP address and gateway, as you noted above. If you're trying to connect to other networks in your address space, it would be preferred to *confirm* that you want the same IP address and gateway, which is why `netsh` expects this info.

Having said that, Powershell will let you, using the CIDR notation. If you know the Interface Index, you can use the following powershell command (as admin):

```
Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex x -PrefixLength y
```

(Replace `x` with the Interface Index of the interface you want to change; replace `y` with the CIDR length for your subnet).

To see what Interface Indexes you have (as well as your other IP settings), you can run:

```
Get-NetIPAddress
```